# Mobile data works on Gmail but not on any browser on Pixel 4a 5G

Tags: browser, connection-issues, mobile-data, google-pixel-4a

I have a Pixel 4a 5G running on the latest Android 12 as of 7/22/22. With mobile data and background mobile data enabled in apps, I can make phone calls and check Gmail, and yet, no browser works: Firefox, Chrome, Duckduckgo. They spin or put a loading bar and eventually say "no network connection".

I've reset the networks and reloaded the base system (system reset), but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try turning your wifi off. Your phone may have grabbed a wireless network redirecting http to a login page. Mine likes to latch on to "xfinitywifi".

Comment: Sure have tried it. . .  No go.  Wifi on/off Mobile data On/Off. . .  Mobile data is definitely being used by Gmail, but not the regular apps like browsers, et. al. . .  Tried another Sim.  Same problem.  Must be some screwed system parameter. . .

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my problem is with 5G.  The phone reports a connection with 5G. However, the 5G connection will not work with Google Voice, nor any app other than Gmail.

I must set the preferred network to LTE to get the phone to work properly. I thought initially that it worked without setting the preferred network to LTE, because the tower at the place where I live has no 5G coverage whatsoever, so the connected network was LTE. The minute the phone connects to a 5G signal, the data service drops out for Google Voice, and all other apps including browsers.

Found a fix.

1. I turned off WiFi.
2. Go to the SIM. Set the preferred network to LTE.
3. Let the phone connect to mobile data.
4. Turned on Airplane Mode.
5. Checked the browser to assure that there was no internet connection.
6. Dismissed the tab, and shut down the browser completely.
7. Turned off Airplane Mode.
8. Waited until the phone reported connection to mobile data (icons at top).
9. Brought up the browser (WiFi is still off), and typed in search.
   Voila, the browser now functions properly on mobile data.

Summation: I don't know if the phone I have is defective, or if my carrier has a problem. I would like the phone to work properly on 5G, though, it's why I bought this model.

I'm leaving this up in the hopes that anyone having the same problem won't have to suffer as I did.